# mail php $from not working

Tags: php, email, hotmail

I'm trying to send a simple mail script from my website to my hotmail account but it keeps coming up as spam (cgi mailer). I know it has something to do with the header well the from part but cant seem to grasp how to get it all to work.. this is what ive got...

```
<?php 
$name =  $_POST['contact_name'] ;
$email = $_POST['contact_email'] ;
$from= "$name <$email>;"
$company = $_POST['contact_company'] ;
$number = $_POST['contact_phone'] ;

// $message = $_POST['contact_message'], "Name:" . $name,"Telephone Number:" .        $number;
$message = $_POST['contact_message'];
$message .= "Name:" . $name;
$message .= "Telephone Number:" . $number;
$to = "bcplumbing-heating@hotmail.co.uk";
$subject = "ContactForm";
$headers = "From:" . $from;

//modify the mail function
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

any help or advice would be great... thanks

Comment: Try changing to `$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";`. This still can't guarantee that it will skip spam.

Comment: i would suggest using phpmailer (http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/). you dont have to think about the headers when you use it, and it has ALOT more advantages.

Answer (score 2):

you may want to use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) class which allow you to hide all that abstractions and even debug mail sending

Answer (score 1):

Hotmail make some complex spam checks. This goes over RBL lists and Reverse lookup.

- So when you send your email from **test@test.de** for example. Then hotmail check if the IP from the sending mailserver goes back to the domain **test.de** (Reverse lookups).
- The next point is that the Email server has a correct configuration.

Perhaps a better way for the application site is to use a mail system which makes it automatically.

I prefer here [Switftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can send mail using SMTP from an email server like gmail, 
to not get it in spam folder. You can use this script:

email page:

```
<?php
require "email.php";

$mail = new EMail;
$mail->Username = 'somthing@mydomain.co.uk';
$mail->Password = 'thepassword';

$mail->SetFrom("some@address.com","Some name");  // Name is optional
$mail->AddTo("someother@address.com","Someother name"); // Name is optional
$mail->AddTo("someother2@address.com");
$mail->Subject = "Some subject or other";
$mail->Message = "Some html message";

//Optional stuff
$mail->AddCc("someother3@address.com","name 3");  // Set a CC if needed, name optional
$mail->ContentType = "text/html";          // Defaults to "text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1"
$mail->Headers['X-SomeHeader'] = 'abcde';  // Set some extra headers if required
$mail->ConnectTimeout = 30;  // Socket connect timeout (sec)
$mail->ResponseTimeout = 8;  // CMD response timeout (sec)

$success = $mail->Send();

?>
```

email.php:

```
<?php

//email.php: Sends an email using an auth smtp connection
//v3

class EMail
{
  const newline = "\r\n";

  private
    $Server, $Port, $Localhost,
    $skt;

  public
    $Username, $Password, $ConnectTimeout, $ResponseTimeout,
    $Headers, $ContentType, $From, $To, $Cc, $Subject, $Message,
    $Log;

  function __construct()
  {
    $this->Server = "127.0.0.1";
    $this->Port = 25;
    $this->Localhost = "localhost";
    $this->ConnectTimeout = 30;
    $this->ResponseTimeout = 8;
    $this->From = array();
    $this->To = array();
    $this->Cc = array();
    $this->Log = array();
    $this->Headers['MIME-Version'] = "1.0";
    $this->Headers['Content-type'] = "text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
  }

  private function GetResponse()
  {
    stream_set_timeout($this->skt, $this->ResponseTimeout);
    $response = '';
    while (($line = fgets($this->skt, 515)) != false)
    {
 $response .= trim($line) . "\n";
 if (substr($line,3,1)==' ') break;
    }
    return trim($response);
  }

  private function SendCMD($CMD)
  {
    fputs($this->skt, $CMD . self::newline);

    return $this->GetResponse();
  }

  private function FmtAddr(&$addr)
  {
    if ($addr[1] == "") return $addr[0]; else return "\"{$addr[1]}\" <{$addr[0]}>";
  }

  private function FmtAddrList(&$addrs)
  {
    $list = "";
    foreach ($addrs as $addr)
    {
      if ($list) $list .= ", ".self::newline."\t";
      $list .= $this->FmtAddr($addr);
    }
    return $list;
  }

  function AddTo($addr,$name = "")
  {
    $this->To[] = array($addr,$name);
  }

  function AddCc($addr,$name = "")
  {
    $this->Cc[] = array($addr,$name);
  }

  function SetFrom($addr,$name = "")
  {
    $this->From = array($addr,$name);
  }

  function Send()
  {
    $newLine = self::newline;

    //Connect to the host on the specified port
    $this->skt = fsockopen($this->Server, $this->Port, $errno, $errstr, $this->ConnectTimeout);

    if (empty($this->skt))
      return false;

    $this->Log['connection'] = $this->GetResponse();

    //Say Hello to SMTP
    $this->Log['helo']     = $this->SendCMD("EHLO {$this->Localhost}");

    //Request Auth Login
    $this->Log['auth']     = $this->SendCMD("AUTH LOGIN");
    $this->Log['username'] = $this->SendCMD(base64_encode($this->Username));
    $this->Log['password'] = $this->SendCMD(base64_encode($this->Password));

    //Email From
    $this->Log['mailfrom'] = $this->SendCMD("MAIL FROM:<{$this->From[0]}>");

    //Email To
    $i = 1;
    foreach (array_merge($this->To,$this->Cc) as $addr)
      $this->Log['rcptto'.$i++] = $this->SendCMD("RCPT TO:<{$addr[0]}>");

    //The Email
    $this->Log['data1'] = $this->SendCMD("DATA");

    //Construct Headers
    if (!empty($this->ContentType))
      $this->Headers['Content-type'] = $this->ContentType;
    $this->Headers['From'] = $this->FmtAddr($this->From);
    $this->Headers['To'] = $this->FmtAddrList($this->To);
    if (!empty($this->Cc))
      $this->Headers['Cc'] = $this->FmtAddrList($this->Cc);
    $this->Headers['Subject'] = $this->Subject;
    $this->Headers['Date'] = date('r');

    $headers = '';
    foreach ($this->Headers as $key => $val)
      $headers .= $key . ': ' . $val . self::newline;

    $this->Log['data2'] = $this->SendCMD("{$headers}{$newLine}{$this->Message}{$newLine}.");

    // Say Bye to SMTP
    $this->Log['quit']  = $this->SendCMD("QUIT");

    fclose($this->skt);

    return substr($this->Log['data2'],0,3) == "250";
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your mail goes straight into the spambox is probably because your `headers` are quite minimal.

Try expanding them like this:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "FROM: DezeActie.nl <noreply@website.com>" . PHP_EOL;    
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Return-Path: noreply@website.com" . PHP_EOL;
```

One thing else to keep in mind is that the `header` containing the `FROM:` part has to be *above* the `Content-type`. Apparently this keeps it from going to the spambox (atleast, I read it on SO and tried it out myself - works).

You can expand the `headers` even further by adding

`$headers .= "Reply-To: Recipient Name <email@website.com>" . PHP_EOL;`

From what I've read, this pretty much prevents your mail from going to the spambox because you provide a lot of info about your mail(format).

Edit: I see people posting about PHPMailer and SwiftMailer. I personally haven't used them but I'm pretty sure they give you a lot of benefits when it comes to formatting your mail function and safety.